# Import 5.5 sql export to 5.0 sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have made a website locally on my mac, using MAMP. Now i need to upload the site to the internet. So i upload the files via FTP, create a database using the Cpanel, and now i want to import the database. But i keep getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;" I just found out that the sql version on MAMP is: 5.5.33 and the version my web provider uses is 5.0.95 could this be the problem?

how do i solve this?

This is the code that it complains about:

```
    CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

\  `meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , \  `comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' , \  `meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL , \  `meta_value` LONGTEXT , \ PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) , \ KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) , \ KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ) \
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Comment: I tested it locally and had not problems (I removed the \ )

Comment: Which one of the slash \ did you remove? because i can't seem to get it to work :(

Comment: I removed all of them.